# Why isn't my ChoiceField rendering from my Django form onto the template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using django forms and trying to render the name of the form object stored in the dictionary key and its corresponding value stores a form.ChoiceField to display on the website. For some reason, it is only displaying the object location in memory e.g. <django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x04B304D8> rather than the dropdown itself. These dropdowns are just a selection from 0 up to N where N is the quantity of the item available in the database. [image: not rendering the choicefield when retrieved from form field]

**Here is my Form Code**

```
    name = forms.CharField(label="Employee Name", max_length = 200, required = False)
    jobsite = forms.CharField(label="Jobsite", max_length = 200, required = True)
    date_needed = forms.DateField(initial = now, required = True)
    SundryFields = {}
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sundries = kwargs.pop('sundries')
        super(CreateNewOrder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # ? it works i guess ? 
        for sundry in sundries:
            quantity_list = [(i, i) for i in range(sundry.quantity_available + 1)]
            self.SundryFields[sundry.name] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=quantity_list)
```

**Here is my View**

````
```def orders(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewOrder(response.POST, sundries = Sundry.objects.all()) # holds information from form 
        if form.is_valid():

            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data

            order = Order(name=cleaned_data["name"], jobsite=cleaned_data["jobsite"], date_needed=cleaned_data["date_needed"])
            order.save()
            # delete these from the order -- no longer needed once an order object is created 
            del cleaned_data["name"]
            del cleaned_data["jobsite"]
            del cleaned_data["date_needed"]

            # ROOM FOR OPTIMIZATION: filter data to only give list of objects that have a quantity requested with them
            def find_requested(cleaned_data):
                requested = []
                for name, value in cleaned_data.items():
                    if int(value) > 0:
                        requested.append(name)
                return requested

            # CREATE ALL ITEMS AND SAVE THEM TO THE ORDER
            for name in find_requested(cleaned_data):
                i = Item(order=order, text=name, quantity_requested=cleaned_data[name])
                i.save()
                # REMOVE FROM QUANTITY AVAILABLE IN SUNDRY MODEL
                Sundry.objects.filter(name=i.text).update(quantity_available = F('quantity_available') - i.quantity_requested)
            
            # HANDLE EMAILING HERE
            subject = 'QCE Warehouse - Order #' + str(order.pk)
            message = 'For: ' + order.name + "\n"
            for item in order.item_set.all():
                message += ("Item Requested: " + item.text + "Quantity: " + str(item.quantity_requested) + "\n")
            message += ("Date Needed: " + str(order.date_needed))
            email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            recipient_list = ['braxtonagoss@gmail.com']

            send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)

            # SEND USER TO THANK YOU PAGE -- TODO: redirect to home after a few seconds
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')

    else: 
        form = CreateNewOrder(sundries = Sundry.objects.all())

    return render(response, "main/order.html", {"sundryList": Sundry.objects.all, "form":form} )
````

**Here is the template**

```
{% block title %}Orders{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    
    <h1>Current List of Available Sundries</h1> 

    <form method = "post" action="/orders/"> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3"> 
            <ul>
            Name: {{form.name}}
            Jobsite: {{form.jobsite}}
            Date Needed: {{form.date_needed}}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <ul> 
        {% for key, val in form.SundryFields.items %}
            <li> {{key}}, {{val}}  </li> 
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <button type="submit", name="submit"> Submit Order </button>
    </form>
    

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In the else statement of orders functions why is that line for `form = CreateNewOrder(sundries = Sundry.objects.all())`  ?

Comment: @FaisalNazik because I need to create the form variables based on the sundries in **kwargs, I tried removing it and got an imeediate keyError when the __init__ function tries to fetch 'sundries'.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these `sundryFields`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I need the name displayed to the user and the dropdown/inputbox to allow the user to submit an order with those quantities selected.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you need to render a `<select>` field for every Sundry object in the `<ul>`?

I would recommend using a `<input type="number" />` field if you have a wide variety of choices / available quantities for each of the items.

Try this:
Change your form init to map the sundry name and the quantity available as calculated to a key value pair:

```
name = forms.CharField(label="Employee Name", max_length = 200, required = False)
jobsite = forms.CharField(label="Jobsite", max_length = 200, required = True)
date_needed = forms.DateField(initial = now, required = True)
SundryFields = {}
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      sundries = kwargs.pop('sundries')
      super(CreateNewOrder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # ? it works i guess ? 
      for sundry in sundries:
         self.SundryFields[sundry.name] = sundry.quantity_available
```

```
<ul> 
  {% for key, val in form.SundryFields.items %}
    <li>
      {{key}}  # This will display the current SundryItem description
      <input type="number" min="0" max="{{val}}"/> # the max number allowed is the sundry.quantity_available for this instance as specified in the form __init__
    </li> 
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: FANTASTIC! works like a charm. Will this work if I want to add bootstrap and make it look nice?

Comment: Great! Happy to hear that. Yes sure, using bootstrap you would just need to add the required classes to the <li> and the <input> HTML elements and of course all others that need styling. It should have no effect on your business logic. Happy coding!

Comment: One more thing if don't mind, the form now doesn't know when these items are selected so it never sends that information to my view.py file. Do you know how I would fix this?

Comment: So the values you add to the input fields never arrive in your orders function as declared in views.py? Could you perhaps add some logging to the function so that I can see what you do get? Are any of your other values there? ie. name, jobsite?

Comment: Yeah the tested name and jobsite arrive back in views because they end up in the emai that is sent by views.py. I'm thinking I'm going to need a form.field() of some kind inside my forms.py but I cannot figure out which type

Comment: You could try a simple IntegerField in your forms __init__? That should do it. Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield

Good luck!